# How to see decompile so file from apk flutter release?

Tags: flutter, dart, security, shared-libraries, decode

I want to decode libapp.so from an apk but I can't see the data clearly using ghex,

Can flutter libapp.so data be decoded?
can you give me the source code / tool that can decode libapp.so data?

I want to see the source code of libapp.so dart